# Отступы между DockPanel

Tags: wpf

Есть вот такая разметка, где я назначаю каждому элементу стиль в котором описаны отсутпы:

```
 <Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"  >
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Width="200" Text="Путь к директории в WORD:" Style="{StaticResource smallMargin}" />
                <TextBox Width="400" Style="{StaticResource smallMargin}"/>
                <Button  Width="50" Content="..." Style="{StaticResource smallMargin}"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel >
                <TextBlock Width="200" Text="Путь к временной папки" Style="{StaticResource smallMargin}"/>
                <TextBox  Width="400" Style="{StaticResource smallMargin}"/>
                <Button  Width="50" Content="..." Style="{StaticResource smallMargin}"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <WrapPanel Style="{StaticResource smallMargin}">
                <TextBlock Text="Режим:" Width="200"/>
                <ComboBox Width="200"/>
            </WrapPanel>
            <Button Margin="0 100" Height="30" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Старт"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Можно ли сделать это как-нибудь по другому и более лаконично, что бы сделать отступы между DockPanel?

Ресурс:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WordParserUI">
    <Style x:Key="smallMargin" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 10 0 0"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Отступ между чем и чем нужен? Покажите ресурс `smallMargin`

Comment: Между DockPanel'ми

Comment: В WPF обычно не используют контролы фиксированной ширины, я про ваши `Width="200"`. Ну и контролу можно задать стиль по умолчанию, который будет действовать на все контролы данного типа на текущем уровне иерархии.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а как уйти на фиксированной ширины, да так, что бы ничего не посыпалось?

Comment: Я напишу ответ как я это вижу.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал примерно так, во-первых, вынес бы текстовое поле и кнопку для выбора пути в отдельный `UserControl` (назвал его `PathBox`):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="..."
            Padding="10,2" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Во-вторых, для табличной разметки предназначен `Grid` и всё можно сделать в нем:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="VIndent">
            <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Путь к директории в WORD:"/>

    <c:PathBox Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource VIndent}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Путь к временной папке:"/>

    <c:PathBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource VIndent}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Режим:"/>

    <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource VIndent}"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Content="Старт" Padding="20,2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Вроде, приколько получилось, но ComboBox неестественно высокие получились. Их же без явного указания высоты не выправить?

Comment: Значит что-то не так как у меня вы сделали

Comment: Если они у вас в той же строке, что и другой контрол, то конечно, они будут по высоте подстраиваться под него. Просто укажите VerticalAlignment="Center", например, потому что по умолчанию там Stretch.